# ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS with named pipe and IO completion port

Tags: python, ctypes, named-pipes, io-completion-ports

I have a simple named pipe server implemented in python+ctypes:

```
pipe = windll.kernel32.CreateNamedPipeA('\\\\.\\pipe\\pipe_name', PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 1, 0, 0, 0, None)

overlapped_struct = OVERLAPPED()

windll.kernel32.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, byref(overlapped_struct))

iocp = windll.kernel32.CreateIoCompletionPort(pipe, None, WPARAM(707070707), 0)

while True:
    bytes_transferred = DWORD()
    completion_key = WPARAM()
    overlapped_struct_ptr = POINTER(OVERLAPPED)()
    windll.kernel32.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, byref(bytes_transferred), byref(completion_key), byref(overlapped_struct_ptr), INFINITE)

    bytes_available = DWORD()
    windll.kernel32.PeekNamedPipe(pipe, None, 0, None, byref(bytes_available))

    buf = create_string_buffer(bytes_available.value)
    ret_code = windll.kernel32.ReadFile(pipe, byref(buf), bytes_available.value, None, overlapped_struct_ptr)
```

It receives data from external program. I expect that `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` will return only when something arrives to the pipe, but it's not always the case. Sometimes, after it dequeues completion packet, I can see that `bytes_available == 0`, `ret_code == 0` and `overlapped_struct.Internal == 256` (which I assume means ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS).

Any ideas on why does it happen?

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Python?  Try specifying `.argtypes` for all your functions to ensure items are marshaled to C correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. A completion packet is queued after **any** operation on a pipe. It means that `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` will return after client connection, write and read operation.

What was happening in my situation:

1. I received data from external program. Completion packet was queued.
2. I read a pipe. Another completion packet was queued.
3. During the subsequent read, if there was no new data in the pipe, `ReadFile` returned 0 and `overlapped_struct.Internal` indicated ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS, which is perfectly correct: there was no new data in the pipe.